# Ошибка при компиляции в консоли: error LNK2001, error LNK1120

Tags: c++, консоль

Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"conio.h"
#include"windows.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    if (!sndPlaySound(L"C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\Sample Music\\Kalimba.mp3", SND_ASYNC))
        cout<<"Error!";
    else
        cout<<"Sound playing!";
    _getch();
}
```

Как устранить эти две ошибки?

Ошибка  1

> error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "**imp**sndPlaySoundW@8"

Ошибка  2

> error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

Comment: А откуда берётся `sndPlaySound`?

Comment: @VladD вроде как Windows.h

Comment: @smackmychi: Хм, и правда. Тогда, скорее всего, не прилинковано `Winmm.lib`. ([Документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает. Только запускает он, даже если указан путь к муз. файлу правильно, стандартные звуки винды, ну, "Дзиин...".